# Python: Display multiple images based on position -> Program paused when image is displayed

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tracking

I am new to python and have a project to do regarding "Person tracking".
I'm making a little prototype trying to display images based on people's position. Top left, Top right, Bottom right, ...

I tried with Tkinter and I manage to display the images and I managed to integrate some of my code to display the images (These are the 5 lines following the "if block.x ..") in my people detection code

My problem is now that when an image is displayed, the program pauses and nothing runs, my code is supposed to display the position of people but it no longer does once the image is displayed.

Does anyone have any idea how to unlock this?

The goal would be to change the image according to the position of the person. (If a person is on the left, display the image of eyes looking to the left for example)

If it can be of help, I am using a Gravity: Huskylens camera and am currently on a Raspberry Pi 3

```
    import time
    import json
    import tkinter
    from huskylib import HuskyLensLibrary
    from tkinter import Label
    from tkinter import mainloop
    from tkinter import Tk
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage
    
    
    
    # Initalize
    # hl = HuskyLensLibrary("I2C","", address = 0x32)
    hl = HuskyLensLibrary("SERIAL", "/dev/ttyUSB0", 3000000)
    
    
    # Change to face recognition algorithms
    hl.algorithm("ALGORITHM_FACE_RECOGNITION")
    
    # Run Screen
    screen = Tk()
    #w, h = screen.winfo_screenwidth(), screen.winfo_screenheight()
    screen.overrideredirect(True) # Real fullscreen, no taskbar
    screen.geometry('1024x10124') # Size of screen, image
    
    while True:
        blocks = hl.requestAll() # Blocks and Arrows
    
        for block in blocks:
            if block.type == "BLOCK": # If block is detected
                if block.x <= 106 and block.y <= 80:
                    image = "Eyes_Top_Left.jpg" # Image to display
                    with Image.open(image) as img:
                        photo = PhotoImage(img.resize((1024, 1024)))
                        Label(screen, image = photo).pack() # Display image
                    mainloop()
    
                    print("Top left !")
                    print('x : ', block.x)
                    print('y : ', block.y)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                if (block.x > 106 and block.x <= 214) and block.y <= 80:
                    image = "Eyes_Top.jpg" # Image to display
                    with Image.open(image) as img:
                        photo = PhotoImage(img.resize((1024, 1024)))
                        Label(screen, image = photo).pack() # Display image
                    mainloop()
    
                    print("Top !")
                    print('x : ', block.x)
                    print('y : ', block.y)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
            else:
                print("No Block")
                time.sleep(0.5)
```

I apologize if this is not clear, do not hesitate to ask for ample information

I tried using the .after () and it more or less seems to work but the problem is that the image doesn't change. When the first is displayed, it does not disappear in favor of another but the program continues to run.

```
def function_to_call():
    print("-------------------------------")
    print("Inside function_to_call()")

#while True:
    blocks = hl.requestAll() # Request for Blocks and Arrows
    print("After hl.requestAll()")

    for block in blocks:
        print("Inside for loop")
    
        if block.type == "BLOCK": # Check if a block is detected
            print("After if block detected")
        
            # Top Right
            if block.x <= 106 and block.y <= 80:
                print("Top right position")
                image = "Eyes_Top_Right.jpg" # Image to display
                print("Image chosen")
                with Image.open(image) as img:
                    photo = PhotoImage(img.resize((1024, 1024)))
                    Label(screen, image = photo).pack() # Display image
                    print("Inside with")
                screen.after(500, function_to_call) # Wait 1 sec then go to function ...
                print("After .after()")
                mainloop()
                print("After .mainloop()")

            # Top
            if (block.x > 106 and block.x <= 214) and block.y <= 80:
                print("Top position")
                image = "Eyes_Top.jpg" # Image to display
                print("Image chosen")
                with Image.open(image) as img:
                    photo = PhotoImage(img.resize((1024, 1024)))
                    Label(screen, image = photo).pack() # Display image
                    print("Inside with")
                screen.after(500, function_to_call) # Wait 1 sec then go to function ...
                print("After .after()")
                mainloop()
                print("After .mainloop()")

print("Calling my function_to_call()")
function_to_call()
print("Function is called")
```

Here is what is print, the program seems to be running, however it never prints the "After .mainloop ()"

We can clearly see the two positions detected, Top and Top Right, but the image displayed has always been that of Top Right.

```
Before function_to_call()
Calling my function_to_call()
-------------------------------
Inside function_to_call()
After hl.requestAll()
Inside for loop
After if block detected
Top right position
Image chosen
Inside with
After .after()
-------------------------------
Inside function_to_call()
After hl.requestAll()
Inside for loop
After if block detected
Top position
Image chosen
Inside with
After .after()
```

I can't figure out how to fix this ..

Comment: You should not call `mainloop()` inside the while loop.  Actually don't use while loop in the main thread of a tkinter application.

Comment: Why is the while loop a problem? It should just spin what's inside continuously right?

Do you have a suggestion to try to change this?

Comment: First `mainloop()` will block the while loop so you cannot call it inside the while loop.  If you move the `mainloop()` out of the while loop then the while loop will block the  application from executing `mainloop()`, then the tkinter pending events cannot be processed.

Comment: Ooh ok thanks i will try to find another way to display my images then

Comment: If `hl.requestAll()` is not a time-consuming function, you can use `.after()` to replace the while loop.

Comment: I tried to call hl.requestAll which is not a time-consuming function according to the doc.

_requestAll( )
Description: Request all block or arrow data from HuskyLens. This will return block/arrow data for all learned and unlearned objects that are visible on the screen.
Returns: Returns data array [block1 , block2, ... blockN] or [arrow1 , arrow2, ... arrowN]_

so I created a function but the problem cited below persists

Comment: You should not call `mainloop()` inside `function_to_call()`.  Call it after first call of `function_to_call()`, i.e. at the end of your code.  Also `screen.after(...)` should be called at the end of `function_to_call()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to concoct what I wanted thanks to the canvas. Now the correct image is displayed based on a person's position.

Here is the code I used for my prototype.

Thanks for your help.

```
# -- Import --
import time
import json
import tkinter
from huskylib import HuskyLensLibrary
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import mainloop
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageTk import PhotoImage

# -- Initalize --
# hl = HuskyLensLibrary("I2C","", address = 0x32)
hl = HuskyLensLibrary("SERIAL", "/dev/ttyUSB0", 3000000)

# Change to face recognition algorithms
hl.algorithm("ALGORITHM_FACE_RECOGNITION")

# Run Tk
screen = Tk()
screen.overrideredirect(True) # Real fullscreen, no taskbar
screen.geometry('500x400') # Size of screen for the image ("background")
canvas1 = Canvas(screen, width = 500, height = 400)
canvas1.pack()

# Eyes Top
Eyes_Top_Right = PhotoImage(file = 'Eyes_Top_Right.jpg')
Eyes_Top = PhotoImage(file = 'Eyes_Top.jpg')
Eyes_Top_Left = PhotoImage(file = 'Eyes_Top_Left.jpg')
# Eyes Middle
Eyes_Right = PhotoImage(file = 'Eyes_Right.jpg')
Eyes_Middle = PhotoImage(file = 'Eyes_Middle.jpg')
Eyes_Left = PhotoImage(file = 'Eyes_Left.jpg')
# Eyes Bottom
Eyes_Bottom_Right = PhotoImage(file = 'Eyes_Bottom_Right.jpg')
Eyes_Bottom = PhotoImage(file = 'Eyes_Bottom.jpg')
Eyes_Bottom_Left = PhotoImage(file = 'Eyes_Bottom_Left.jpg')

while True:
    blocks = hl.requestAll() # Camera request for Blocks and Arrows

    for block in blocks: # for loop
        if block.type == "BLOCK": # Check if a block is detected
        
            # Top Right
            if block.x <= 106 and block.y <= 80:
                eyesTopRight = canvas1.create_image(230, 150, anchor = NW, image = Eyes_Top_Right) # PosX, PosY, Anchor, Image
                screen.update_idletasks()
                screen.update()
                time.sleep(0.5)

            # Top
            if (block.x > 106 and block.x <= 214) and block.y <= 80:
                eyesTop = canvas1.create_image(230, 150, anchor = NW, image = Eyes_Top) # PosX, PosY, Anchor, Image
                screen.update_idletasks()
                screen.update()
                time.sleep(0.5)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You should update your question instead of posting it as an answer.